# Get X first/last WORDS from string

Tags: php, string

OK, this is what I need...

**Example input :**

`$str = "Well, I guess I know what this # is : it is a & ball";`

**Example Output :**

- `firstWords($str,5)` should return `Array("Well","I","guess","I","know")`
- `lastWords($str,5)` should return `Array("is","it","is","a","ball")`

I've tried with custom regexes and `str_word_count`, but I still feel as if I'm missing something.

Any ideas?

Comment: why not `explode()` the string and gather elements from an array then??

Comment: str_word_count and preg_split are what immediately comes to mind. What are you missing?

All you need, then is to slice the array of words (array_slice)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need is

```
$str = "Well, I guess I know what this # is : it is a & ball";
$words = str_word_count($str, 1);

$firstWords = array_slice($words, 0,5);
$lastWords = array_slice($words, -5,5);

print_r($firstWords);
print_r($lastWords);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Well
    [1] => I
    [2] => guess
    [3] => I
    [4] => know
)

Array
(
    [0] => is
    [1] => it
    [2] => is
    [3] => a
    [4] => ball
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function cleanString($sentence){
    $sentence = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/","",$sentence);
    while(substr_count($sentence, "  ")){
        str_replace("  "," ",$sentence);
    }
    return $sentence;
}

function firstWord($x, $sentence){
    $sentence = cleanString($sentence);
    return implode(' ', array_slice(explode(' ', $sentence), 0, $x));
}

function lastWord($x, $sentence){
    $sentence = cleanString($sentence);
    return implode(' ', array_slice(explode(' ', $sentence), -1*$x));
}
```

Comment: Looks like OP just needs words and to ignore symbols like commas `Well` not `Well,` as well as `&` `:` and `#` need ignored so exploding on a space wouldn't work best here

Comment: ah, i missed that. updated my code with a lame-ass clean function. it will still have troubles with "I'm" and stuff like that but certain characters can be added to the regex white list

Answer (score 0):

Here is for firstWord:

```
function firstWords($word, $amount)
    {
        $words = explode(" ", $word);
        $returnWords = array();

        for($i = 0; $i < count($words); $i++)
        {
            $returnWords[] = preg_replace("/(?![.=$'€%-])\p{P}/u", "", $words[$i]);
        }

        return $returnWords;
    }
```

for lastWords reverse for loop.